# How to align images to the right and text to the left?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to set my layout to appear as follows:

[image]

Using the following XAML:

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="txtSiteName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <tabs:TabItem Name="tabSettings" TabItemText="Settings" 
                  TabItemImage="settings.png" Margin="5" />

        <tabs:TabItem Name="tabDelete" TabItemText="Delete Site" 
                  TabItemImage="delete.png" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

However, it's appearing as:

[image]

What do I need to do to get the images to align to the right, and have the text vertically aligned on the left?

Comment: That should work fine (minus the redundant dependencies) but you might share more of your code to show the parent containers that I can only assume are influencing these as children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parent container isn't stretching to fill the available space.

You can try

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
<!-- etc -->
```

and, if that doesn't work, move up the tree until you find the element that's not stretching.

**OP Edit in support of the correct answer:**

It turns out this is correct - A parent container wasn't stretching to fill the space.

The parent container was the ListBox that I was inserting the items into.

Where before I had just this:

```
    <ListBox Name="SiteListBox" Grid.Row="2" />
```

I changed it to the following to force the containing ListBoxItems to stretch:

```
    <ListBox Name="SiteListBox" Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="txtSiteName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"/>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <tabs:TabItem Name="tabSettings" TabItemText="Settings" 
              TabItemImage="settings.png" Margin="5" />

        <tabs:TabItem Name="tabDelete" TabItemText="Delete Site" 
              TabItemImage="delete.png" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the TextBlock's Vertical Alignment to Center.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="txtSiteName" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <tabs:TabItem Name="tabSettings" TabItemText="Settings" 
              TabItemImage="settings.png" Margin="5" />

        <tabs:TabItem Name="tabDelete" TabItemText="Delete Site" 
              TabItemImage="delete.png" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And try switching your column definitions.